# Uniformly continuous Cauchy sequences in R

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that a uniformly continuous image of a Cauchy sequence is Cauchy. Show by counterexample that uniformly is necessary.

I have figured out the first part. It is sufficient to find $f(a_n)$ which is Cauchy, but I am not sure about how to proceed with the counterexample. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the definition of uniformly continuous? Do you know the definition of Cauchy?

Comment: How about you tell us what you've done, thought, tried?

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the first part. It's not enough to prove that some uniformly continuous image is Cauchy; you're meant to prove that every uniformaly continuous image is Cauchy.

Comment: For the counterexample, do you know an example of a function that is continuous but not uniformly continuous?

Comment: Yes, I think $f(x)=x^2$ could be such an example.

Comment: Good. But, probably better to find one based on a finite interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take , $X=(0,1)\subset \Bbb R$ and $\displaystyle f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ , is NOT uniformly continuous in $X$ ; and take $\displaystyle x_n=\frac{1}{n}$ , which is Cauchy in $(0,1)$ but $\{f(x_n)\}$ is NOT Cauchy.

Comment: Good, but I wonder whether it's cheating to use a function defined only on $X$, when the title of the question refers to sequences in $\bf R$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Question says Cauchy sequence in $\Bbb R$. Here $\{x_n\}$ is Cauchy sequence in $X$ as well as in $\Bbb R$.